# Azure Function QueueTrigger - Put new items back on queue

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function based on a `QueueTrigger`. This gets triggered when something appears on the queue, but after I processed this item, I then want to put new items back on the queue.

Is there a way to do this directly from within the Azure Function?

```
[Function("Batch")]
public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("batch", Connection = "DataQueue")] string data,
    FunctionContext context)
{
    var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(data);

    // 1. process model
    // 2. Put items back on queue?
}
```

Comment: You just use a QueueClient to re-add it. There is no special way in the function

Answer (score 0):

You can use output bindings as the following:

```
[StorageAccount("MyStorageConnectionAppSetting")]
public static class QueueFunctions
{
    [FunctionName("QueueOutput")]
    [return: Queue("myqueue-items")]
    public static string QueueOutput([HttpTrigger] dynamic input,  ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# function processed: {input.Text}");
        return input.Text;
    }
}
```